# Отступы у полей в Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, css

В Firefox у input'ов текст опускается на 1 пиксель вниз. Сбрасывал всё, но не помогает. display: inline-block и всякие overflow тоже не решили проблему.

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0}
body {background: #fff; font-size: 11px; font-family: tahoma; line-height: 1}
```

http://montytool.ru/md/test.php

В Chrome, текст в поле выглядит нормально, а в Firefox он спадает на 1px;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вижу разницу. Да отступ есть. А что это такая великая проблема? А вообще вы это как веб-пользователь или разработчик спрашиваете?

Comment: @MrGons18, это на самом деле великая проблема. Я привык, что во всех браузерах должно быть всё одинаково. Даже в старых версиях IE мой сайт смотрится на 5+ ;)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

слева лиса (iceweasel 15), справа хромиум (22)
вот разную ширину инпута и разный шрифт вижу, а положение текста вроде бы одинаковое

Comment: @modos189, вот так у меня http://clip2net.com/clip/m40641/1354635564-clip-8kb.jpg

Comment: а с другими шрифтами тоже такая проблема?

Comment: @modos189, да. Тоже такая проблема.